# Is $X^T X$ invertible if $p > n$?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, linear-algebra

I am checking other's regression analysis work on a $p > n$ data. I can only see the results but not the process how he did it.

I believe he made mistakes. Since $p > n$, $X^T X$ is not full rank it is not invertible. So we cannot find the OLS coefficient.

However, I am not sure my reasoning is correct. I have not used linear algebra for a long time.

Update:

1. No penalized methods involved.
2. He used stepwise regression for variable selection. A new question: would such algorithm stop if number of variables in the model equal to the number of sample points?
3. His goal is to find out which variables are important. Doesn't care about the prediction power.

Comment: Yes you are correct in that $X^TX$ is non-invertible. However, perhaps your colleague performed some penalized regression like LASSO to get coefficients?

Comment: What are $p$ and $n$?

Comment: A bit more context may be useful. Is the goal forecasting? Is it consistently estimating some effect $b_i$? Do you know if your colleague performed LASSO or ridge regression?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo $p$ and $n$ are classically the number of covariates and of independent observations. IE, $X$ is $n \times p$.

Comment: If he's using forward stepwise regression, he'd never have more than $n$ variables in the actual regression matrix used (starting from 1 = the intercept, finding the best variable to add incrementally.)  That's not to say forward stepwise regression (or any stepwise regression) is good, it's just to say it would have avoided the identifiability problem.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be, "In today's age, is forward step-wise regression an acceptable method to find useful predictors?"

Comment: It is possible for $X^\prime X$ not to be invertible yet for the least squares solutions to exist; moreover, it can even be possible to identify variables related with the response and to find that their coefficients can be estimated accurately.

Answer (score 5):

If matrix $\mathbf X$ is $n \times p$ and $p > n$, then it is **fat** and, thus,

$$ \mbox{rank} (\mathbf X) = \mbox{rank} \left(\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X \right) \leq n < p $$

Hence, $\mathbf X^\top \mathbf X$ does not have full rank and, thus, it is *not* invertible.